# Lambda can't parse input when triggered from Kinesis

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a C# AWS Lambda function which is being triggered from AWS Kinesis and it's failing before it even gets to my code. The error I am getting is

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: 1. Path 'Records[0].kinesis.approximateArrivalTimestamp', line 1, position 302.: JsonReaderException
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsDateTime()

I have used the method signature given in the tutorial [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-kinesis-example-deployment-pkg-dotnet), which looks like this:

```
[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
public void HandleKinesisRecord(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent)
{
}
```

Is this the correct signature I should be using? Looks like there might be a mismatch between the JSON Kinesis is sending and Lambda is expecting.

Comment: Can you please turn on CloudTrail and post a capture of the input event to your lambda for us to see? - thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Xavier. I have turned on CloudTrail. But it just seems to be pick up high level API calls. Are you sure it tracks Lambda invocations? I noticed CloudWatch captures these logs, but it doesn't dump the actual incoming json.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: No. I just took the raw JSON as an input and used that.